# How to convert a number to 0.mynumber

Tags: c++, numbers, converters

How can i convert a number to 0. and the number?

so

```
int i = 50;
float a = 0.i //wrong code :D
```

or what?
how can i do it?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to get `a = 0.01` or `a = 0.001` for some values of `i`?

Comment: Are you expecting `a == 0.50`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float a = i;
while( a >= 1.0f ) a /= 10.0f;
```

Comment: Sorry, but *MISRA* is getting to me.  You should have `/= 10.0f`.  Note the decimal point and the `f` suffix to indicate a `float` constant.

Comment: @BarışUşaklı Thanks. (I should really not answer questions on the side while actually concentrating on other stuff :-P)

Comment: @DanielFrey isn't that what everyone is doing? :P

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but I think this works:

```
    int i = 50;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0." << i;
    float a;
    ss >> a;
```

Comment: Heh... any time a numeric operation involves going to and from a string, I cringe. There's probably something more elegant with bit shifting, but this is the hack I came up with faster.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

float zero_dot( float m ) {
   return m / pow( 10.0, floor( log( m ) / log( 10.0 ) ) + 1 );
}

int main() {

   for( auto const & it: { 5.0, 50.0, 500.0, 5509.0, 1.0 } ) {
      std::cout << it << ": " << zero_dot( it ) << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
5: 0.5
50: 0.5
500: 0.5
5509: 0.5509
1: 0.1
```

The computation does not use any loop.

Comment: I thint that is a little bit too complicated for this little project :)

Comment: @ShakeryGO: Can you please tell me what is complicated here? This is the closed form of Daniel Freys answer. (Also: Why are little projects 'simpler' than bigger ones?)